# Visual Studio 2012 Scroll issue in Design View

Tags: visual-studio, view, scroll

While position stuff in a .aspx using a Master Page, I lost the the ability to scroll horizontally using the scroll bar in design view of visual studio 2012. The bar is greyd out like if it was disabled.
Altought, I can still see the whole page in a browser.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs so they can get fixed in the next service pack.

Comment: Not a option, need to deliver it until sunday..